# How to insert space after every semicolon of a string in Perl?

Tags: regex, string, perl

I'm trying to insert a space after every semicolon of a string in Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
my $string = "1234;5678;232;5774;9784";
$string =~ s/;/"; "/g;
my $matched = $1;
print $matched . "\n";
```

But it doesn't work. My string is `1234;5678;232;5774;9784`. I want to print `1234; 5678; 232; 5774; 9784`. thanks

Comment: So it just prints out the original string again?

Comment: The error message says `Use of uninitialized value $matched in concatenation (.) or string at...`. The regex is not matching anything in the string.

Comment: Add `print $string, "\n";` to the end and you will see that matching has occurred.  What has not occurred is capturing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to print `$string` not `$matched`. Also, you don't need the quotes in the regex, unless you want them in there as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "1234;5678;232;5774;9784";
$string =~ s/;/; /g;
print "$string\n";
```

prints `1234; 5678; 232; 5774; 9784`